# Configuring a virtual machine to use a different Internet connection

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, virtualbox, internet, connection

I have two Internet connections on my PC: one is through the local network and the other is wifi. The computer runs Windows 7, and I use VirtualBox to run Windows XP virtually.

How can I configure Windows 7 to use the wifi connection exclusively, and XP to use the local network connection exclusively?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the wifi connection can get to the internet, Windows 7 should use that.

To tell VirtualBox to use the LAN connection, you'll need to go into the settings for that VM in VirtualBox. Click on "Network" on the left hand side. Choose "Bridged Adapter" and then choose the LAN adapter. Click OK and boot up your VM, it should only have access to whatever the LAN connection really has access to.